# I want to create a table using React JS by passing the values in props using an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ajax, react-native

I am building a Table component of a big project and I have build tables before, but I am unable to create a table through the format I have been given to work on.
What I am trying to do here is, In the **RecordTable Component**, Rendering the **table component** and passing the **row component** through it, and again passing the **column component** through it and then finally performing the function.
The code that i have been working on for so long is mentioned below, but it isn't yielding any great results.

In *App.js*

import {rowData} from "../src/Component/MockData";

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RecordTable
      rowData = {rowData}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

For *RecordTable.js*

```
    import Table from "./Table";
import Row from "./Row";
import Column from "./Column";
import "./style.scss";

const RecordTable = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Table>
        {
          props.rowData && <>
            <Row>
              {Object.keys(props.rowData[0]).map((key,keyIndex) =>(
                      <Column>{key}</Column>
                    ))}
            </Row>
          </>
        }
        {
          props.rowData ? props.rowData.map((row,rowIndex) =>(
            <Row>
                {Object.values(row).map((value,valueIndex) =>(
                    <Column>{value}</Column>
                  ))}
            </Row>
          ))
       :'' }
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

For Row.js and Column.js,Table.js The Data go as follows,

```
    const Row = ({children}) => {
      return (
        <div className="record-table-row" >
            {children}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    function Column({children}) {
        return (
            <div className="record-table-column">
                {children}
            </div>
            
        )
    }
function Table({children}) {
    return (
        <div className="record-table">
        {children}
            
        </div>    
    )
}
```

For Reference, The Data in the MockData looks like this,

```
const rowData = [{"Task ID":"SLC-1", "Task Name": "When either of task or bug is assigned to resources from any resources", "Status":"To-Do", "Assignee":"User-1", "Priority":"Highest", "Epic": "", "User Story": "", "Sprint":"Sprint-1", "Complexity":"High", "Dependent Resources": "Tushar", "Estimated Efforts(in-Hours)":0, "Actual Time Spend":1, "Start Date": "16-june-2021", "End Date": "1-Dec-2021", "Description":"For Project Task, Prefix should be #1", "Created At":"16-june-2021", "Created By": "Tushar", "Updated At":"16-june-2021","Updated By":"Tushar Sharma" },
{"Task ID":"SLC-2", "Task Name": "When either of task or bug is assigned to resources from any resources", "Status":"Dev Done", "Assignee":"User-2", "Priority":"High", "Epic": "", "User Story": "", "Sprint":"Sprint-1", "Complexity":"High", "Dependent Resources": "Tushar", "Estimated Efforts(in-Hours)":0, "Actual Time Spend":1, "Start Date": "16-june-2021", "End Date": "1-Dec-2021", "Description":"For Project Task, Prefix should be #1", "Created At":"16-june-2021", "Created By": "Tushar", "Updated At":"16-june-2021","Updated By":"Tushar Sharma" },
{"Task ID":"SLC-3", "Task Name": "When either of task or bug is assigned to resources from any resources", "Status":"Dev Done", "Assignee":"User-3", "Priority":"Highest", "Epic": "", "User Story": "", "Sprint":"Sprint-1", "Complexity":"High", "Dependent Resources": "Tushar", "Estimated Efforts(in-Hours)":0, "Actual Time Spend":1, "Start Date": "16-june-2021", "End Date": "1-Dec-2021", "Description":"For Project Task, Prefix should be #1", "Created At":"16-june-2021", "Created By": "Tushar", "Updated At":"16-june-2021","Updated By":"Tushar Sharma" },
{"Task ID":"SLC-4", "Task Name": "When either of task or bug is assigned to resources from any resources", "Status":"To-Do", "Assignee":"User-4", "Priority":"High", "Epic": "", "User Story": "", "Sprint":"Sprint-1", "Complexity":"High", "Dependent Resources": "Tushar", "Estimated Efforts(in-Hours)":0, "Actual Time Spend":1, "Start Date": "16-june-2021", "End Date": "1-Dec-2021", "Description":"For Project Task, Prefix should be #1", "Created At":"16-june-2021", "Created By": "Tushar", "Updated At":"16-june-2021","Updated By":"Tushar Sharma" },
{"Task ID":"SLC-5", "Task Name": "When either of task or bug is assigned to resources from any resources", "Status":"Dev Done", "Assignee":"User-5", "Priority":"Low", "Epic": "", "User Story": "", "Sprint":"Sprint-1", "Complexity":"High", "Dependent Resources": "Tushar", "Estimated Efforts(in-Hours)":0, "Actual Time Spend":1, "Start Date": "16-june-2021", "End Date": "1-Dec-2021", "Description":"For Project Task, Prefix should be #1", "Created At":"16-june-2021", "Created By": "Tushar", "Updated At":"16-june-2021","Updated By":"Tushar Sharma" }  ]

export {rowData}
```

I just want the components to be returned in the same order as in RecordTable.js,
Other than that, We can use any methodology that yields the results.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own table, you might want to use this library called Material-UI.

https://material-ui.com/components/tables/

The simplest way to create the table is:

```
<DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} pageSize={5} />
```

You can install the Material-UI by following this link:
https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/

Comment: I do not want to use any library, is there any other way of doing so as per my code?

Answer (score 0):

`<></>` syntax may noy be supported by your tools. Try `<React.Fragment>`.
For more information you may look [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#support-for-fragment-syntax). Besides that your code is working.

Comment: The column width is not equal for table headers and table rows.
And I have tried different CSS but still no results.